# LiquiBase : populating a changelog property value with an sql query?

Tags: java, sql, database, liquibase

I tried to use the property tag of Changelog to define a counter value queried from a counter Table like this :

```
<property name="counter" value="Select counter from counterTable" dbms="mysql"/>
```

and then

```
<column name="id" defaultValue="${counter}" />
```

But that doesn't work.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I assume you are actually running against mysql. What Liquibase version are you running? What is the error you are seeing?

Comment: Actually I got no error in the console but the DB is not updated. I am just wondering whether it is possible in principle to use an SQL Query inside a property value instead of a procedure call ?

Comment: It should work just fine. Although it works best with defaultValueComputed="${counter}"

Comment: thanks for your help. I've found that it was just a typo.

Comment: Good. Was there a better error message I could put in to make it more obvious?

Comment: What is the right answer to this question, please? I'm new to Liquibase and don't really understand the gist of what it said in the comments, that is, I don't know how that can be achieved.